# Php pagination feature does not work at all

Tags: php

I want to enable pagination on the page. But I couldn't make it. Although the site has a "pagination" feature, this feature does not work on this page. All "items" appear on the same page. Actually, pagination appears properly but all item are on one page even if you click on the other pages.  UPDATED: I have added .tpl file.

```
<?php
class component_SmileList extends SK_Component 
{
    
    private $folder;
    
    private $conv_list;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('smile_list');
    }
    
    public function prepare( SK_Layout $Layout, SK_Frontend $Frontend )
    {
        $handler = new SK_ComponentFrontendHandler('MailboxConversationsList');
        
        $handler->construct();
                
        $this->frontend_handler = $handler;
    
                
        parent::prepare($Layout, $Frontend);
    }
    
    
    
    public function render( SK_Layout $Layout )
    {
        $profile_id = SK_HttpUser::profile_id();
        $smile_list = app_Smile::getProfileSmiles($profile_id);
        
        mysql_query('UPDATE `skadate_smileme` SET `notify_status` = 0 WHERE `interlocutor_id` = "'.$_SESSION['%http_user%']['profile_id'].'"')or die(mysql_error());

        $service = new SK_Service('read_message');
        $serv_perm = $service->checkPermissions(); 
        $show_rdbl = false;
        
        if ($serv_perm != SK_Service::SERVICE_FULL) {
            $Layout->assign('perm_msg', $service->permission_message['message']);
            
            $ms = app_Membership::profileCurrentMembershipInfo($profile_id);            
            if ($ms['type'] == 'subscription' && $ms['limit'] == 'unlimited')
                $show_rdbl = true;
        } 
        
        $Layout->assign('check_rdbl', $show_rdbl);
        $Layout->assign('smile_sent_msg', SK_Language::section('send_smile')->text('smile_sent_msg'));
                
        $Layout->assign('paging', array
        (
            'total'     => $smile_list['total'],
            'on_page'   => SK_Config::Section('site')->Section('additional')->Section('mailbox')->mails_per_page,//Same as mail
            'pages'     => SK_Config::Section('site')->Section('additional')->Section('profile_list')->nav_per_page//Same as mail
        ));
        $Layout->assign('smile_arr', $smile_list['smiles']);
        
        $Layout->assign('profile_id', $profile_id);
        
        return parent::render($Layout);
    }
    
    
    public function handleForm( SK_Form $form )
    {
        switch ( $form->getName() )
        {
            case 'manage_mailbox':
                /*$form->frontend_handler->bind('success', "function(data) {
                    this.ownerComponent.reload({folder: '".SK_HttpRequest::$GET['folder']."'});
                }");*/
                break;
                
            case 'send_message_page':
                if ( isset(SK_HttpRequest::$GET['username']) )
                {
                    $form->getField('recipient')->setValue(htmlspecialchars(SK_HttpRequest::$GET['username']));
                }
                $form->getField('sender_id')->setValue(SK_HttpUser::profile_id());
                break;
        }
    }
    
}
```

```html
{* component smile_list *}
{canvas}

{container text_ns='components.mailbox_conversations_list' stylesheet="smile_list.style"}

    {block}
    {if $smile_arr}
    {form ManageSmilelist mark_for=$profile_id} 
    
        {foreach from=$smile_arr item='smile'}

        <table class="mailbox_threads">

            <td class="status {if $smile.bm_read eq 1} new_smile {/if}"> 
            </td> 
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auth_thumb">
                    
                    {profile_thumb profile_id=$smile.sender_id size=60 }
            </td>
            <td id="user_date">
                    <a href="{document_url doc_key='profile' profile_id=$smile.sender_id}">{$smile.username}</a><br/>
                    
            </td>
            <td class="actions list_item">
            <a href="{document_url doc_key='profile' profile_id=$smile.sender_id}">{$smile.username}</a>{$smile_sent_msg}

            </td>
            <td class="deneme">
{$smile.time_stamp|spec_date}

            </td>
                    <td class="chbox">{input_item name="smiles" value=$smile.smile_id}</td>
        {/foreach}</table>
    
        

            <div class="selectall"><td class="chbox"><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /></td>
            <td colspan="2"><label for="select_all">&nbsp;&nbsp;{text %select_all}</label></td></div>
            <div class="selectall2"><td class="subject_message no_border" colspan="2">
                {button action='mark_read'}
                {button action='remove' class="delete"}
            </td></div>
    
    
    {/form}
    {else}
            <div class="no_content">{text %no_content_smile}</div>
        
    {/if}
    {/block}
    {paging total=$paging.total on_page=$paging.on_page pages=$paging.pages}
{/container}
{/canvas}
```

Comment: I removed Smarty and JavaScript tag as I don't see how they are applicable here. If I am wrong please add them back in

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have added .tpl file. I tried to examine why it doesn't work but couldn't find it. I haven't tried to make it work. I didn't wrote it. So no idea what i need to do. Maybe you'll give an advice.